# Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type'(String)'

Tags: swift

What is wrong here and how to solve this problem?

```
struct Venue {
    let building: String
    var rooms: [String]?
}

func addRoom(building: String, room: String) {
    if let venueIndex = find(venues.map {$0.building}, building) {
        venues[venueIndex].rooms.append(room) //Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type'(String)'
    }
}

var venues: [Venue] = [...]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `venues[venueIndex].rooms` is not a `[String]` but a `[String]?`.  Optionals don’t have an `append` method – the value wrapped inside them might, but they don’t.

You could use optional chaining to do the append in the case where it isn’t `nil`:

```
venues[venueIndex].rooms?.append(room)
```

But you may instead want to initialize `rooms` to an empty index instead when it is `nil`, in which case you need to do a slightly messier assignment rather than an append:

```
venues[venueIndex].rooms = (venues[venueIndex].rooms ?? []) + [room]
```

However, it is worth asking yourself, does `rooms` really need to be optional?  Or could it just be a non-optional array with a starting value of empty?  If so, this will likely simplify much of your code.